# REACT: Why my custom hook does not read the initial parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here is my hook:

```
export default function useShift(activeShiftInfo,itoRosterList,setITORosterList){
  const getShiftCssClassName=(shiftType)=>{
    let shiftInfo=activeShiftInfo[shiftType];
    if (shiftInfo===undefined){
      return '';
    } else {
      return shiftInfo.cssClassName;
    }
  }
  return [getShiftCssClassName]
}
```

Here is the code that consume the hook:

```
import React,{useContext} from "react";
import BorderedAlignCenterCell from './BorderedAlignCenterCell';
import RosterWebContext from '../../../utils/RosterWebContext';
import useShift from '../hooks/useShift';
import './ShiftCell.css';
export default function ShiftCell(props){
  let {activeShiftInfo,itoRosterList,setITORosterList}= useContext(RosterWebContext);
  
  let [getShiftCssClassName]=useShift(activeShiftInfo,itoRosterList,setITORosterList);
  let finalClassName=getShiftCssClassName(props.children)+" shiftCell";
  return(
    <BorderedAlignCenterCell
      {...props}
      className={finalClassName}>
      {props.children}
    </BorderedAlignCenterCell>
  )
}
```

where variables activeShiftInfo,itoRosterList are state variable.

The error message states the useShift.js:5 the value of the `activeShiftInfo` variable is undefined.

However, I print the content of `activeShiftInfo` in the ShiftCell.js:8, it can return a value.

Would you mind telling me the reason for this error?

Comment: `useShift` is not a custom hook TBH. Doc says: A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use” and **that may call other Hooks.**

Comment: Usually when you can console.log a value, but somewhere in your code it says undefined.  It's usually because of something `async`,  I can't see anything async here, so it's maybe higher up your code base that we don't see here.

Comment: @MurliPrajapati  I up-voted your comment, but now looking at description, it would imply it is a hook..  The term `may`, IOW: doesn't have to include other Hooks.  Personally I would still just call it a function.

Comment: @MurliPrajapati do you mean because the name 'getShiftCssClassName'  does not start with 'use', therefore it does not a 'hook'?

Comment: @Keith @TheKNVB `useShift` is not a hook because it doesn't follow the rules of hook i.e it can be called from any js function apart from react components and the order of it does not affect the component rendering. If it included a hook then it must be at top level but as per current code, it doesn't matter from wherever you call it.

Comment: @TheKNVB `useShift` should at least have a default/custom hook in it so that React can warn you if you break the rules of hooks. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html